How does Luke know that removing Vader's mask will kill him?
In Return of the Jedi, towards the end, Darth Vader says he wants Luke to take his (Vader's) mask off:

VADER   (a whisper)
Luke, help me take this mask off.
LUKE
But you'll die.

How could Luke have known that? We see other characters wearing masks (from Storm Troopers to bounty hunters) and none of them would die without the mask.
Additionally, though it might be convenient to say "Obi-Wan told him at some point off-screen" we have no way of knowing how Obi-Wan would know. When he left Anakin, Anakin was dying sans legs, and on fire.
Assuming that (if Anakin is Darth Vader...I don't know when Obi-Wan learned that, or how) Vader's standing makes "new legs" an obvious inference, is there an equivalent "tell" that would help Luke (and/or Obi Wan) know that the mask keeps Vader alive?

already answered on SciFi https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87767/how-did-luke-know-vader-needed-his-helmet-to-survive

for future reference, which board is this more suited for?

it depends... https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376/how-do-you-distinguish-when-a-question-should-be-asked-at-se-movies-vs-se-scifi

According to the Return of the Jedi Junior Novelisation, it was already apparent to Luke that Vader's helmet and chestplate were part of a "breathing apparatus". Presumably the throaty breathing noises would have given it away, even without Luke's Jedi senses.
That being the case, Luke could have reasonably assumed that removing Vader's helmet and mask would kill him:

From where he lay, Luke could tell by the rasping rattle from Vader’s
helmet that his breathing apparatus was broken. Luke crawled the short
distance to his father’s side and pulled him away from the edge of the
abyss.
...
Luke didn’t have to look at the life systems computer on Vader’s
chestplate to know what his father was suggesting. Luke said, “But
you’ll die.”


beat me to it hahaha

@Luciano Likewise, was just about to hit Enter. C'est la vie. +1.

This is a copy/pasta of my answer on another site - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87767/how-did-luke-know-vader-needed-his-helmet-to-survive

yeah I mentioned it in a comment, only realized it was your own answer when I came back here.
